# Remember me for WebFlux Security application with SESSION and X-CSRF token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I have a NextJS app that communicates with a Spring backend, I'm getting the SESSION and X-CSRF cookie correctly but they only last for the browser session, when the browser window is closed and then reopened I want my users to be able to still be in the session and not have to login again every time.

I know that Spring Security has "Remember me" unfortunately I'm using WebFlux Security and ServerHttpSecurity doesn't have the remember me functionality, I saw this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5504 but couldn't understand well what they mean with the solution.

I'm using Spring Session and since we can't have remember me, I don't know what exactly are the best steps to take? Would I have to set the Max Age of both cookies and used them for the days that I want my users to be logged in? Is this the best course of action?

I don't want to migrate to regular Spring Servlet Security unless it was the only way to solve this.

Comment: the github issue says you can use spring session and store sessions in an external source like for instance mongo to get the functionality you need. Read the spring session documentation.

Comment: Exactly I'm using Spring Session, but that's not really the answer. My problem is when the browser closes. Regular Web Security has remember me cookie to auto login users when they reopen the browser window. Since WebFlux Security doesn't, I'm asking if the best practice would be to set the Max-Age of both cookies to the desired time. Using spring session by itself doesn't solve my issue, the only thing would be setting the max age of the cookie like Spring Session says, but that's what I'm asking, if that's the best way.

Comment: i never claimed that my comment was an answer, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Since RememberMe isn't on WebFlux Security applications therefore the only solution I think of, is with the cookies.

You could modify the session cookie in the webflux application by using this [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-webflux-custom-cookie.html) from Spring Session, for the CSRF token, you could set the max age on CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository, like it was implemented [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/11433) and that change is coming in the next Security versions.

By setting the max age, you can still use the same session when you reopen the browser window, unless the server session times out.

I don't know if that's the best solution, but if someone wants to add something else that would be great.